# How to convert a string to RegularTimePeriod in java?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using Jfreechart. I have the code like this:

```
TimeSeries t1 = new TimeSeries("EUR/GBP");
t1.add(new Day(4, MonthConstants.JANUARY, 2001), new Double(1.5807));
```

But I get `String` from my SQL query. TimeSeries accepts only `RegularTimePeriod` or `TimeSeriesDataItem`.

Please let me know how to convert a `String` into `RegularTimePeriod`.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which String? What does the String look like?

Answer (score 3):

First you can get a Date object by parsing your mysql date string using a SimpleDateFormat, then create your RegularTimePeriod using the constructor with a Date arg.

Basically (assuming mysqlDateStr is your string from mysql query) :

```
SimpleDateFormat standardDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
// (Define your formatter only once, then reuse)

Date myDate = standardDateFormat.parse(mysqlDateStr);
// (you may want to catch a ParseException)

t1.add(new Day(myDate), new Double(1.5807));
```

Comment: Of course you would have to change the String in simple date format to match the date.